# Page numbering is only shown a page after the title

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

The code used for the numbering is stated below. I want the top line to match with the page that shows list of tables

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \pagestyle{fancyplain}
    %
    \pdfbookmark[-1]{Front Matter}{frontmatter_anchor}
    %
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make a compilable minimal working example, including a class and the necessary packages to compile your code?

Comment: By "top line" do you mean the header?  That would depend on the fancyplain definition.

Comment: Please don't use `\pagestyle{fancyplain}`. It is deprecated, and might give undesirable results.